# When value of a column changes in one table , a record should be inserted in other table in oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, function, procedure

I want a SQL procedure / function to solve the below mentioned problem:

I have 2 tables - Table A and table B.

- Table A has 3 columns - name, number and flag.
- Table B has 2 columns - name and number.

When a value of flag column changes in table A, a record should be inserted in table B with the same values of name and number from table A.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Triggers are made for such purpose. see for example here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using triggers.

[Triggers are procedures that are stored in the database and are implicitly run, or fired, when something happens](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm).

You can write triggers that fire whenever and INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operation is performed  on a particular table or view.

General Syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER WRITE_TRIGGER_NAME_HERE
  BEFORE UPDATE ON TABLE_A
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  WRITE_INSERT_STATEMENT_HERE_FOR_TABLE_B
END;
```

Comment: just one little point, OP stated he wanted operations to be made `AFTER` data was inserted/updated, or is the outcome equivalent and it is just the time difference if you write `BEFORE` instead of `AFTER`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste valid point. For me the question is a bit unclear so I just gave a general pointer to the OP.